# getattr in current function

Tags: python

Is there a way to get the variable of `name` in the below?

```
def save_info(self):
    name = 'hello'
    var1 = 'other item'
    var2 = 1
    ...
    TV_SERIES_FIELDS_TO_UPDATE = ['name', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4', ...]
    for field in TV_SERIES_FIELDS_TO_UPDATE:
        current_value = getattr_or_none(obj, field)
        new_value = # how do I get the variable of `name` ("hello") ?
```

Given a string of the variable name, how would I get its value within the current function?

Comment: ...what? Have you tried `new_value = name`?!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the variable of `name`"?

Comment: Do you need to store the variable names as strings in the list? You can just store the variables themselves.

Comment: @mattm -- yes, I need to store them as strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals):

```
def save_info():
    name = 'hello'
    var1 = 'other item'
    var2 = 1
    TV_SERIES_FIELDS_TO_UPDATE = ['name', 'var1', 'var2']
    for field in TV_SERIES_FIELDS_TO_UPDATE:
        print field, locals()[field]

save_info()
```

However, I'd urge you consider using an explicit dictionary instead of having a bunch of unrelated variables.

Answer (score 1):

You have two option

Access local variables

```
def save_info(self):
    name = 'hello'
    var1 = 'other item'
    var2 = 1
    ...
    TV_SERIES_FIELDS_TO_UPDATE = ['name', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4', ...]
    for field in TV_SERIES_FIELDS_TO_UPDATE:
        current_value = getattr_or_none(obj, field)
        new_value = locals().get(field)
```

but if I were you I would rewrite the code and use dictionary.

```
TV_SERIES_FIELDS_TO_UPDATE = { 'name_of_the_show': 'value', 'second_show': 'value2' }
for key, value in TV_SERIES_FIELDS_TO_UPDATE.items():
    new_value = # od some magic with value
```